# How to add a comment to a cell in Excel using Xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Im trying to add a comment to cell A1 with the following code and this causes the jupyter notebook to freeze. On restarting I notice an empty comment was inserted on A1.

```
sht.range("A1").api.AddComment="My comment"
```

How can I add a comment to a cell? The actual VBA is

`sht.Range("A1").AddComment "My comment"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it.

```
sht.range("A1").api.AddComment(Text="My Comment")
```